# Как обратить операцию "остаток от деления"?

Tags: python, математика

Есть выражение `x * 6015 % 26 = 4`. Мне необходимо осуществить обратную операцию, чтобы вычислить число `x`. Пока что реализовал только операцию кодирования, а с декодированием мыслей нет.

UPD: Диапазон возможных значений числа `x`: от 0 до 25

Comment: 14%3 = 2.  47%3 = 2.  2%3 = 2. Это намек: однозначное декодирование не получится...

Comment: по остатку -никак

Comment: @Harry, а если я еще знаю возможный диапазон числа x ? К примеру от 0 до 25

Comment: Если знаете диапазон, то проще построить карту обратных преобразований и не париться. `{x * 6015 % 26:x for x in range(26)}`  -> `{0: 0,
 1: 3,
 2: 6,
 3: 9,
 4: 12,
 5: 15,
 6: 18,
 7: 21,
 8: 24,
 9: 1,
 10: 4,
 11: 7,
 12: 10,
 13: 13,
 14: 16,
 15: 19,
 16: 22,
 17: 25,
 18: 2,
 19: 5,
 20: 8,
 21: 11,
 22: 14,
 23: 17,
 24: 20,
 25: 23}`  Отсюда вытекает, что искомое число  `x = 12`.

Comment: @Интик, видимо только им и можно, только пока не особо представляю, как именно это реализовать

Comment: @GrAnd, спасибо за мысль, очень помогли

Comment: @GrAnd, если не лень, оформите ответ, галочку поставлю

Comment: Ну и, кстати, взглянув на полученную карту, легко вывести обратную формулу - `x = остаток * 3 % 26`

Comment: @GrAnd, это вообще великолепно, благодарю)

Comment: [Расширенный алгоритм Евклида](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/export_extended_euclid_algorithm) решает задачу. Ещё тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1039660.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если знаете диапазон, то проще построить карту обратных преобразований и не париться.

```
numbers_map = {x * 6015 % 26:x for x in range(26)}
# {0: 0,  1: 3,  2: 6,  3: 9,  4: 12,  5: 15,  6: 18,  7: 21,  8: 24,  9: 1,  10: 4,  11: 7,  12: 10,  13: 13,  14: 16,  15: 19,  16: 22,  17: 25,  18: 2,  19: 5,  20: 8,  21: 11,  22: 14,  23: 17,  24: 20,  25: 23}
def get_source_number(num):
     return numbers_map[num]
```

Отсюда вытекает, что искомое число `x = 12`.

Answer (score 2):

Если вас интересует общее решение, то полный перебор - это не то, что вам нужно.

Математически ваша задача формулируется так: найти числа `x` и `y` такие, что `6015*x + 26*y = 4`

Это уравнение имеет решение, так как эти два числа взаимно просты: `gcd(6015, 26) = 1`. Расширенный алгоритм Евклида `gcd_extended(A,B)` возвращает три числа - `gcd(A,B)`, `u`, `v` такие что `A*u + B*v = gcd(A,B)`

```
def gcd_extended(A,B):
    if A == 0:
        return (B, 0, 1)
    _gcd, v, u = gcd_extended(B % A, A)
    return (_gcd, u - (B // A) * v, v)
```

В вашем случае

```
g,u,_ = gcd_extended(6015, 26)
assert(g == 1)
x = 4*u
```

ответ: `x` равно 12.

## Общий случай

Нужно решить уравнение `(x*A)%B = C`

Другими словами, нужно решить диофантово уравнение `A*x + B*y = C`

Это уравнение имеет решение в том и только том случае, если `C` делится на `gcd(A,B)`.

Решается так: расширенным алгоритмом Евклида найдем `u`, `v` такие, что `A*u + B*v = gcd(A,B)`

Тогда `x = u*C/gcd(A,B)`

```
def invert_mod(A,B,C):
    "Вернуть x такое, что (A*x)%B = C. Если решения нет, вернуть None."
    g, u, _ =  gcd_extended(A, B)
    if 0 != (C % g):
        return None
    return (u*C//g)%B
```

В вашем примере `invert_mod(6015, 26, 4)` вернет 4.